# Google aouth token and Picasa

Tags: android, picasa

I am trying to get the photos from a users google plus / picasa account. I was wondering if i could use the oauth token from here 
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#server-side_access_for_your_app 
to work with picasa https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#ListAlbums or are these not related.